# Subversion 1.7 installation on Ubuntu

Tags: svn, ubuntu, apt

I'm having troubles on SVN installation, I need a VM with subversion 1.7 but when I check which versions exist on source list I see just the next:

```
apt-cache showpkg subversion
Provides: 
1.8.8-1ubuntu3.1 - 
1.8.8-1ubuntu3 -
```

So I cannot make:

```
apt-get install subversion=1.7.n
```

someone knows how to install it or modify source list to make this installation possible?

Comment: Checked the apache page (https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#ubuntu) and if you're unable to add an apt repository with older versions you'll need to get it from wandisco: https://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download

Comment: hey! I tried to download the package from the subversion.apache.org but when I make ./configure, errors pop, when I download the installing script from wandisco, it just ask me if I want to install svn, I answer Y (yes), and then it does nothing for the entire time.

Comment: Are you running the script as root?

Comment: yep, done it too but nothing happens, anyway I just made all in svn 1.8 cause my work is about dump and load and they're all both compatibles.